# Assigning a column for a modified dataframe back to original dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function that modifies a dataframe and then passes back a column from the modified dataframe. The code looks like this:

```
def foo(df):
    ser = (df[df['bool']].groupby('group')['date'].min())
    # Hackish way to merge back to df
    serdf = pd.DataFrame(ser, columns=['date_trigger'])
    serdf['group'] = ser.index.values
    df = pd.merge(df, close_series, how='left', on='group')
    return df['trigger_date']

dfFinal['trigger_date'] = foo(dfFinal)
```

When I print df in foo just before the return statement, it has all the values in the right place and is the correct length. However, dfFinal['trigger_date'] has NaT in a bunch of places.

Just to get a sense of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to select, by group, the minimum date when a condition is met and assign it to a new column:

```
Group    bool    date
  A       n      2000-01-01
  A       n      2000-03-02
  A       y      2000-04-10
  A       y      2001-01-01
  B       n      2000-02-20
  B       y      2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-04-27
  B       y      2001-01-10
```

This would become:

```
Group    bool    date          trigger_date
  A       n      2000-01-01    2000-04-10
  A       n      2000-03-02    2000-04-10
  A       y      2000-04-10    2000-04-10
  A       y      2001-01-01    2000-04-10
  B       n      2000-02-20    2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-03-15    2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-04-27    2000-03-15
  B       y      2001-01-10    2000-03-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I need to recreate your data:

```
a = pd.io.parsers.StringIO("""  A       n      2000-01-01
  A       n      2000-03-02
  A       y      2000-04-10
  A       y      2001-01-01
  B       n      2000-02-20
  B       y      2000-03-15
  B       y      2000-04-27
  B       y      2001-01-10""")
b = "Group    bool    date".split()
d = DataFrame([i.split() for i in a], columns=b)
```

For a solution, how about:

```
dic = {'y':True, 'n':False}
d['bool'] = d['bool'].apply(lambda x: dic[x])
trigger = d[d['bool']].sort('date').drop_duplicates('Group').drop('bool', axis=1)
d = d.merge(trigger, how='left', on='Group', suffixes=['','_trigger'])
```

**EDIT:**

The OP wants a **Series** as a result, and with the **same index** as the original DataFrame. So I copied @waitingkuo's groupby function and adapted the answer to suit the OP's needs. I hope someone shows a more idiomatic way of solving this one!

```
def trigger(df):

    def min_y(d):
        return d[d['bool'] == 'y'].date.min()

    dt = df.groupby('Group').apply(min_y)
    dt = DataFrame(dt, columns=['trigger_date']).reset_index()
    ix = df.index.copy(deep=True)
    df = df.merge(dt, how='left', on='Group')
    ser = df['trigger_date']
    ser.index = ix
    return ser
```

Comment: I tried this as well. It's a nicer way to get the result, but I have the same problem. It looks fine in the function, but when I try to pass the series back through the function, all I get are NaTs.

Comment: You never mentioned you had single unpaired Series(es) instead of a DataFrame. You need to provide an example that's faithful to your context so that our solutions apply. Can you re-state your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The problem is as I stated it. I'm passing in a dataframe and passing back a column which I then assign to a column of the original dataframe.

Comment: @Luke, both solutions (I prefer @waitingkuo's) give you the resulting DataFrame, not a Series. Just assign the result to the same name. If you are using a REPL, you can just run `type(df)` or `df.head()` to check that.

Comment: I can't do that architecturally. This is one in a long series of feature creation functions that I am sequentially calling and checking for success. I have other functions that return a column with no problem. It's just this case where there is an issue. I'm stumped.

Comment: How about `dfFinal['trigger_date'] = foo(dfFinal)['trigger_date']`? I'm sure you can select the column you want even within the function, and then add it to your DataFrame.

Comment: I tried that and strangely enough, it doesn't work. There's something about the modified dataframe that makes it impossible to pass the column to the original dataframe. Could this be a bug?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45413/discussion-between-dmvianna-and-luke)

Answer (score 2):

Groupby `Group` first and then apply your customized function:

```
In [34]: def func(df):
   ....:     df['trigger_date'] = df[df.bool == 'y'].date.min()
   ....:     return df
   ....: 

In [35]: df.groupby('Group').apply(func)
Out[35]: 
  Group bool                date        trigger_date
0     A    n 2000-01-01 00:00:00 2000-04-10 00:00:00
1     A    n 2000-03-02 00:00:00 2000-04-10 00:00:00
2     A    y 2000-04-10 00:00:00 2000-04-10 00:00:00
3     A    y 2001-01-01 00:00:00 2000-04-10 00:00:00
4     B    n 2000-02-20 00:00:00 2000-03-15 00:00:00
5     B    y 2000-03-15 00:00:00 2000-03-15 00:00:00
6     B    y 2000-04-27 00:00:00 2000-03-15 00:00:00
7     B    y 2001-01-10 00:00:00 2000-03-15 00:00:00
```

Comment: I thought you couldn't select specific rows in a groupby object. Also, isn't `df[df.bool == 'y'].date.min()` a different size than df?

Comment: @Luke, this function is being applied to parts of df that together make a whole df. A groupby object is a mapping, not a df.

Comment: @dmvianna Not sure I understand your point. Do you mean that when you use an apply on a groupby mapping, you can treat the object received by apply as a portion of the original df?

Comment: @waitingkuo, I tried this out today. It almost worked. I was able to create a series of the requisite length. However when I return it, I get the error `Wrong number of items passed` even though it is in fact the correct length. As a reminder, I'm passing back the series rather than the df due to architectural constraints.

Comment: @Luke, yes. Series.apply() will apply a function to every element of the Series. Every object is a portion of the entire Series. Groupby will apply a function to every portion of the DataFrame that matches a value in the grouping Series(es). Together all groups make the whole DataFrame.